# Java graphics fill doesn't paint over graphics draw?

Tags: java, awt

If you run the code below, you will see that there is a red square with a blue line along the bottom and right edges of the square. However, as you can see in the code, the parameters for the rectangle being drawn are the same as the rectangle being filled.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
        }
    };

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Does anyone know the reasoning behind this behavior? Or is this a bug in Java's codebase?

It seems like drawing the rectangle adds 1 to the width and height of the rectangle you specify. This seems like un-intuitive behavior for one, but in my case it is also causing some undesired effects for a gui I am building.

This behavior is also found when drawing polygons with horizontal/vertical lines. Is there a simple way of getting some consistency in what is painted between the graphics draw and fill functions? It would be great if there was a way for any arbitrary polygon to completely paint over a previously drawn polyline using the same points.

One approach I had thought of was to both draw and fill whenever I want to fill a polygon and then just draw when I want to draw the polygon.
This would actually work in cases of opaque polygons, but in my case I have both opaque and transparent polygons so this approach is not an option.

Comment: [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) should be your first port of call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly documented in the [Graphics API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html):

> **drawRect**
>
> public void drawRect(int x,
>               int y,
>               int width,
>               int height)
>
> Draws the outline of the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width. The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height. The rectangle is drawn using the graphics context's current color.

and

> **fillRect**
>
> public abstract void fillRect(int x,
>               int y,
>               int width,
>               int height)
>
> Fills the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width - 1. The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height - 1. The resulting rectangle covers an area width pixels wide by height pixels tall. The rectangle is filled using the graphics context's current color.

Note the difference in the calculation for the right and bottom edges. Although this difference is clearly documented, there is no justification for this difference.

Finally, note that the first line of `paintComponent()` should be `super.paintComponent(g);`. This will ensure that the super class has a chance to initialize things, including clearing the region where you will draw.

Comment: you're right, I did forget that, this is just supposed to be a sample program to demonstrate the problem so I wasn't too worried about it. In any case this is not an answer to the question; the same behavior can be observed when I call super first

Comment: @jdodle I realized I didn't really answer your question after rereading. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the update, good to know this is documented. Do you happen to know what the reasoning behind this behavior is? It seems like if drawing is supposed to provide an outline of the rectangle then it should have the top edge at y-1 and the left edge at x-1 right?

Comment: @jdodle I do not. I just went straight to the API docs to see what it said. All I know is what I copied and pasted here. I suggest that you bookmark the Java API docs for reference. (Or just google the class and/or method name when you have questions such as this.)